# Public member 'value' on type 'Boolean' not found vb.net datatable

Tags: .net, vb.net, datatable, boolean

I am having an issue that is driving me insane and I'm not sure it's just not me being stupid

I have a datatable where I add a boolean column

```
  ds.Tables(0).Columns.Add(New DataColumn("Select", System.Type.GetType("System.Boolean")))
  ds.Tables(0).Columns("Select").ReadOnly = False
  ds.Tables(0).Columns("Select").DefaultValue = False
  ds.Tables(0).Columns("Select").SetOrdinal(0)
```

I then iterate through it and check to see if the column has a true value bit I get the error "Public member 'value' on type 'Boolean' not found" on the Convert.ToBoolean part of the expression

```
For Each dr As DataRow In Categories.Tables(0).Rows
  If dr("Select").value IsNot Nothing AndAlso (Not IsDBNull(dr("Select").value)) AndAlso Convert.ToBoolean(dr("Select")) = True Then
      'Do Something
  End If
Next
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's not where your problem is. Your problem is at the beginning of the `If` statement. The type returned by the indexer is `Object`, which does not have a `value` property or field. You really just want to say this:

```
If dr("Select") IsNot Nothing ...
```

But this condition will never be false, because NULLs are represented by `DBNull` instances. Instead, use this `If` statement:

```
If Not dr.IsNull("Select") AndAlso Convert.ToBoolean(dr("Select")) Then
```

To be more VB, you can do this as well

```
If Not dr.IsNull("Select") AndAlso CBool(dr("Select")) Then
```

And, to borrower from Tim's answer, you can use the `Field()` extension method (see: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datarow.field(v=vs.90).aspx) like so:

```
If If(dr.Field(Of Boolean?)("Select"), False) Then
```

Maybe that's too clever, but it gets the job done.

Answer (score 2):

A `DataRow` or `Object` has no `value` property.

Use the strongly typed [`Field`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb360891.aspx) extension method instead:

```
For Each dr As DataRow In Categories.Tables(0).Rows
    Dim isSelected As Boolean? = dr.Field(Of Boolean?)("Select")
    If isSelected.HasValue AndAlso isSelected Then
        'Do Something
    End If
Next
```

It also supports nullable types as the `Nullable(Of Boolean)` above.

If you are below .NET 3.5 you have to cast manually:

```
For Each dr As DataRow In Categories.Tables(0).Rows
    If Not dr.IsNull("Select") AndAlso DirectCast(dr("Select"), Boolean) Then
        'Do Something
    End If
Next
```

Comment: Note, only .NET 3.5 and above support the `Field()` extension, which I agree is a pretty nice one.

Comment: @siride: Edited my answer accordingly.